# How to change text of my app in "open in" dialog?

Tags: ios

I've used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) in order to add my application to the list of choices a user sees when they tap-and-hold on an attachment in Mail. Everything is working, but my problem is that my application's icon is labeled "Open in {my application}". We wish to have this instead say "Forward with {my application}" or even just "{my application}". Is there any way to change what this says here?

Answer (score 2):

That text is fixed as part of the standard `UIDocumentInteractionController`. There is no setting or API that allows an app to specify a different label. Submit an [enhancement request to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).